# Como posicionar automaticamente foto em um fundo

Tags: php

eu estou com um problema, eu preciso saber como posicionar corretamente e automaticamente uma foto em um fundo qualquer, por exemplo eu quero esse avatar (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTivs.png) fica posicionado no campo que está AVATAR 180x180 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmhud.jpg).

Mas eu preciso fazer que qualquer avatar de 180x180 caiba em outras imagens, por exemplo essa: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbvxX.png

Eu tentei este código mas não funciona, acredito que seja as coordenadas que estão incorretas, só está aparecendo o fundo.

```
$newNome = md5(time()) . ".jpg";
$mainphoto = imagecreatefromjpeg("foto.jpg");
imagecopymerge($mainphoto, "fundo.jpg", 10, 10, 0, 0, 180, 180, 100);
header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg($mainphoto, $newNome, 50);
imagedestroy($mainphoto);
```

Comment: Já tentou inverter os parâmetros do imagecopymerge, primeiro o fundo depois o avatar?

Comment: @fernandoandrade sim tentei mas não funciona.

Comment: Já fiz algo parecido só que foi usando a lib WideImage